# Adding the word Null to a CSV file

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, python-3.6

My query grabs data and puts it into a CSV file. As you can see below I have added a mapping to say  if any fields equal to 1970-01-01 00:00:00 put it to null before writing to the CSV.

However I am getting errors when I do this mapping.

My Code:

```
from datetime import datetime
import csv



csv_file = 'File_' + str(datetime.now().strftime('%Y_%m_%d - %H.%M.%S')) + '.csv'


header_names = { 'VT': 'Side',  'NCR': 'ExTime',  'N': 'Name', 'DT': 'Party', ' RD ': 'Period', ‘DATE’:’Date’}

with open(csv_file, 'w', newline='') as f:
    w = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames=header_names.keys(), restval='', extrasaction='ignore')
    w.writerow(header_names,)
    for doc in res['hits']['hits']:
        my_dict = doc['_source']


mapping = {0: "None",1: "yes", 6: "no", 9: "maybe", 100:"no/yes", 101: "no/maybe"}
VT1 = my_dict['VT']
my_dict['VT'] = mapping.get(int(VT1), VT1)

mapping1 = {0: "New", 1: "Cancel", 2: "Future"}
DT1 = my_dict['DT']
my_dict['DT'] = mapping1.get(int(DT1), DT1)


mapping2 = {1920-01-01 00:00:00: 'Null'}
PT1 = my_dict['DATE']
my_dict['DATE'] = mapping2.get(int(PT1), PT1)


w.writerow(my_dict)
```

Error one:

```
mapping2 = {01/01/1970  00:00:00: ' '}
                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid token
```

Error two

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/rich/.PyCharmCE2017.2/config/scratches/CSV.py", in <module>
    my_dict['DATE'] = mapping12.get(int(PT1), PT1)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '1920-01-01 00:00:00'
```

How am I able to say if the date equals to 1920-01-01 put the word Null?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your entry has no datatype.

If you're dealing with strings then it should be a string.

```
mapping2 = { "1920-01-01 00:00:00": "Null" }
PT1 = my_dict['DATE']
my_dict['DATE'] = mapping2.get( PT1, PT1 )
```

Comment: Hi, i added the above however i still get the error of: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/rich/.PyCharmCE2017.2/config/scratches/csv.py", line 257, in <module>
    my_dict['DATE'] = mapping2.get(int(PT1), PT1)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '1920-01-01 00:00:00'

Comment: Would you know how to do this?

Comment: Don't typecast PT1 as an `int`, it should work. You can't typecast a String of a date into an integer. You should go over the datatypes and make sure you're using them correctly.

Comment: you able to show me in my code? i have been struggling on this alot. If you dont mind showing me ? i think i am using the correctly its just this date is giving me the issue